# python Sphinx not recognizing modules inside project

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to create autodoc for my python project. the problem is that when I am trying to do `make html` it's not working...

my project tree looks like -

```
   - docs
   - EDA_miner
```

When the EDA miner contains all the code 
https://pasteboard.co/If8dT8AS.png - project tree

in the sphinx's conf.py I configured like -

```
   sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
```

but when I am trying to generate using `make html` I get

```
   WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'app' from module 'EDA_miner'; 
   the following exception was raised:
   No module named 'server'
   WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'menus' from module 'EDA_miner'; 
   the following exception was raised:
   No module named 'server'
```

when I am opening ipython and importing server.py it succeed, how am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi Meir, could you give us a little bit more information about whats going on inside EDA_miner?

I've hit this same "autodoc: failed to import module..." error and it usually has to do with funky import statements.

Comment: Oh! Also, don't forget to run `make html` from within your virtual environment (or just be sure to have all your python dependencies installed)

Comment: Thanks you, fixed it, it really was one of the dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make to run `make html` from within your [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html) (or just be sure to have all your python dependencies installed)